# Join two tables with condition on the first table

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I want to make these two into one SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM activegroupmodel 
WHERE groupID = ? 
ORDER BY groupModelID DESC 
LIMIT 1

SELECT * 
FROM model 
WHERE modelID = ?
```

As you can see from the first groupID is not a pk and I want the latest model from that table.
I'v tried this but it obviously didn't work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM activegroupmodel as a 
WHERE a.groupID = ? 
ORDER BY a.groupModelID DESC 
LIMIT 1 
INNER JOIN model as m ON a.modelID = m.modelID
```

I've read a bunch of questions with JOIN but none of them matches my problem.
Anybody knows how I can solve this?
Best regards Johan

Comment: maybe you should put the JOIN before the WHERE

Comment: It was that simple... Thank you @marcosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put your JOIN before the WHERE condition, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM activegroupmodel as a
INNER JOIN model as m ON a.modelID = m.modelID
WHERE a.groupID = ? 
ORDER BY a.groupModelID DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM activegroupmodel as a 
INNER JOIN model as m ON a.modelID = m.modelID
WHERE a.groupID = ? 
ORDER BY a.groupModelID DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct join statement should be as

```
SELECT * 
FROM activegroupmodel as a 
INNER JOIN model as m ON a.modelID = m.modelID
WHERE a.groupID = ? 
ORDER BY a.groupModelID DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM activegroupmodel as a 
INNER JOIN model as m ON a.modelID = m.modelID
WHERE a.groupID = ? 
ORDER BY a.groupModelID DESC 
LIMIT 1
```